# Consider the interval I_n = [a_n, b_n], Assume I_n+t is contained in I_n. Use MCT to prove {a_n} converges to a and {b_n} converges to b with a <= b

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the MCT states that a sequence converges it is is bounded and monotone, but I have no idea how to show that {a_n} is bounded or monotone.

Comment: Do you ever check off an answer as correct?  It appears you have many questions, but none correct.  Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ for all $n$ a and its bounded above by $b_1$. You can do the same to the sequence $(b_n)$ with a little modification. Now you need to prove that $a \leq b$

Comment: So you would say that since a_(n+1) >= a_n and a_n is bounded above by b_n, then a_n is monotonically increasing and bounded, therefore a_n converges? And do likewise for b_n?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, but with $(b_n)$ they would be decreasing and bounded below by $a_1$.

Comment: can we assume that since we have the interval [a_n, b_n] then all elements of {a_n} <= {b_n} so since {a_n} converges to a, then a < = {b_n}

Comment: @user180069 Yes, that works! As an extra you could try doing it by contradiction (supose $a_n$ converges to some $a > b$ and arrive at a contradiction HINT: $a-b = \varepsilon > 0$)

Comment: I just want to try your way of contradiction. so we would say, suppose not and a > b. Then a-b = epsilon > 0. Then since {a_n} converges to a, then abs(a_n - a) < epsilon = a-b, so a-b -a < a_n < a-b + a. Then b < a_n which is the contradiction because since a_n is in [a_n, b_n] then a_n should be less than b?

Comment: @user180069 Im sorry you have to take $\varepsilon = \dfrac{a-b}{2}$, then argue that $a - a_n < \varepsilon = \dfrac{a-b}{2}$ multiply the inequality by $-1$ and then try to arrive at a contradiction

Comment: ok now you lost me... so we say suppose a > b, and abs(a_n - a)< epsilon. choose epsilon = (a-b)/2 > 0. then (a-b)/2 -a < a_n < (a-b)/2 + a. But then going through all the algebra, you get (-a-b)/2 < a_n < (3a-b)/2 which I am failing to see the contradiction

Comment: When multiplying by $-1$ you get $a_n - a > \dfrac{b - a}{2}$ now this means $a_n > a + \dfrac{b - a}{2} = \dfrac{a}{2} + \dfrac{b}{2}$ but $a > b$ thus $a_n > \dfrac{b}{2} + \dfrac{b}{2} = b $ And this cannot happen because $b_n$ would have to be less (strictly) than $a_n$ at some point for some $n$ wich cannot happen.

Comment: I'm sorry, where are you getting a - a_n < epsilon? shouldn't it be abs(a_n - a) < epsilon? Are you manipulating that absolute value in some way?

Comment: Remember that the $a_n$ are increasing into its limit $a$ so $a - a_n$ is non negative ($\geq 0$), so you dont need to take absolute value.

Comment: ok I get it now, thanks so much!!